# How do I continue writing text in PIL from where I left off the last line

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

So this is not about multilining. I just wanna write one text and then write another text from where the last one ended, ie one line below from that. For example, I have 2 strings say 
Quote = "blah blah blah"
Author = "-blah"
And I wanna draw the text on an image so that I can put the author just in the next line from where the quote ended. Assume the quote is multilined

Answer (score 0):

PIL modules PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.text method will do it, go through the [this link](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.text)

```
 PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.text(xy, text, fill=None, font=None, anchor=None)
```

xy is Top left corner of the text. You can do something like this

PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.text((227,160),text_to_add,(0,0,0),font=font)

(227,160) are the x,y co-ordinates and (0,0,0) is the color of the text in rgb.